# ODBC for MSSQL v17 Error - Invalid table name syscharsets for schema sys

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm getting the below error when trying to establish an ODBC connection via Azure AD to a Dynamics CRM 365 DB instance. The connection gets established successfully (with an admin account) but then I can't do anything beyond that.
[image: Error]

It is worth noting that I can connect to the database in SSMS with the same credentials I'm trying to use in this ODBC connection
[image: Succesfull connection]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62828372/2144390